# dhtmlxGrid filterByAll and updateFromXML

Tags: javascript, xml, dhtmlx

I am using dhtmlxGrid library.

I am using the function updateFromXML to update the  grid every few mins with fresh data ( on a timer  ).

My problem is when I add mygrid.filterByAll(), the updateFromXML functionality breaks. It does not do inserts or deletes of  the new rows. It just does the updates of existing rows. 
The doAfterUpdate function I have shown below has the broken code.

If I remove the line mygrid.filterbyAll everything works fine as expected.

Below is my code. I  have shown a template of what I am doing .

```
  <div id="gridbox" style="width:50%; height:500px; background-color:white;"></div>
  <br>
  <div><a href="#" onClick="start_timer_jobs()">Reload grid - Timer refresh data only </a></div>
  <br>
  <script>

var curr_sort = null;
var fetch_interval = null ; 


function doAfterUpdate() { 

mygrid.filterByAll(); ////something broken here. 
if ( curr_sort.length > 0 ) {
console.log ( 'setting sorting' ) ;
    var col_type = mygrid.getColType(curr_sort[0]);
    mygrid.sortRows ( curr_sort[0] ) ;
    }
 return ;
}


function fetch_data ( ) { 

curr_sort = mygrid.getSortingState();

var file_list = [ 'first.xml', 'second.xml', 'third.xml', 'first.xml', 'second.xml', 'third.xml' ] 
var random_number = Math.floor((Math.random()*5));
var url = './test_dirs/' + file_list[ random_number ] 
console.log ( 'fetch data ' +  url ) ; 
mygrid.updateFromXML(url, true, true , doAfterUpdate );



}

function start_timer_jobs ( ) { 

console.log ( 'in timer' ) ; 

if ( fetch_interval ) clearInterval(fetch_interval); 
fetch_interval = setInterval(function() { fetch_data(); }, 10*1000);


}

mygrid = new dhtmlXGridObject('gridbox');
mygrid.setImagePath("./imgs/");
mygrid.setHeader("Sales,edtxt,ed,Price,In Store,Shipping,Bestseller,Publication");
mygrid.setColumnIds("Sales,edtxt,ed,Price,Store,Shipping,Bestseller,Publication");
mygrid.attachHeader("#numeric_filter,#text_filter,#numeric_filter,#numeric_filter,#numeric_filter,#numeric_filter,#numeric_filter,#text_filter");

mygrid.setInitWidths("50,150,100,80,80,80,80,200");
mygrid.setColAlign("right,left,left,right,center,left,center,center");
mygrid.setColTypes("ro,edtxt,ed,ro,ro,ro,ro,ro");

mygrid.setColSorting("int,str,str,int,str,str,str,str");
mygrid.init();
mygrid.enableColumnMove(true); 
mygrid.enableSmartRendering(true);
mygrid.preventIECaching(true);
mygrid.setSkin("dhx_skyblue");
mygrid.loadXML("./test_dirs/grid.xml"  );

  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue using filters on grids.

Pretty sure you need to:

- remove the filter
- then refresh the grid
- put the filter back on

If this does not work, then use clearAndLoad() instead: 
http://forum.dhtmlx.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=19603